# EFCore 7 - Query expression with GroupBy results in EF internal System.ArgumentNullException 'collection'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Converting from net framework over to core, and that comes with moving Entity Framework 6 over to EFCore 7.

I have a keyless View configured:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MySampleView>(entity =>
        {
            entity
                .HasNoKey()
                .ToView("MySampleView");
```

My query is simple and previously worked fine with EF6 under Framework. Filter, Group, ToDictionary

```
 var result = await context.MySampleView
     .Where(x => ... SomeConditions)
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2, x.Column3 })
     .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key.Column1,
     x => new { x.Key.Column2, x.Key.Column3, ... });
```

*Note - there will not be a duplicate key here - Column1,2,3 are always the same*

However, this will throw an exception that comes from within the EF7 framework.

`Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'collection')`

Stack trace put this inside the EFCore source:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'collection')
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument) in /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ThrowHelper.cs:line 284
```

*Apologize for the screenshots here, as I can't seem get the full Stack Trace from VS in text format for some reason.*

[image: Stack Trace View]

Digging through the symbol source, I can see where this is happening, but it shouldn't be happening.

You can see it passing this nullable `_preGroupByIdentifier` into it. In this case, null. (this is MS Symbol Source)
[image: From the stack, this is responsible for the variable]
MS Ref Source: [SelectExpression ref 1](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/82e96d9eb550125d18e4f456a7ff80f1fb292a43/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/SqlExpressions/SelectExpression.cs#L914)

I validated that it should NOT be null, but this is tricky.  I am not sure if there is some optimizer issue or just my debugger is lying to me here. the `_preGroupByIdentifier` should be set to an empty list here, but it's totally skipped as shown here. This is from the MS Symbol Source - Note, for other queries, I have seen it not skip that second breakpoint. What is going on with this? *I don't think this error would be happening if this was not skipped over!*

[image: _preGroupByIdentifier not being set inside if statement]
MS Ref Source: [SelectExpression ref 2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/82e96d9eb550125d18e4f456a7ff80f1fb292a43/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/SqlExpressions/SelectExpression.cs#L1985)

As a work around, this works and no errors, but puts the GroupBy/Dictionary into the standard Linq/Entities. This is not the right way to do it, as the projection should be handled by the SQL server + EF, not shaped in memory in the dotnet app.

```
 var result = (await context.MySampleView
     .Where(x => ... SomeConditions)

     .ToListAsync())  // Running the ToListAsync first - not desirable

     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2, x.Column3 })
     .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key.Column1,
     x => new { x.Key.Column2, x.Key.Column3 });
```

Help me find what I am missing here.

Comment: *as the projection should be handled by the SQL server* - answer for yourself which SQL should be generated. As I know it is terrible ineffective in EF6 implementation.

Comment: EF Core still has issue processing `GroupBy` queries which have no direct SQL translation,  i.e. queries with `GroupBy` which do not select keys/aggregates afterwards. I'm afraid you have to modify your query/queries like this. In that regard, it will be useful to see what the `...` in your sample is, because everything you've shown is just a group keys, which can easily be handled with simple `Select` + `Distinct`. In general you should always preselect all the things that you need inside `ToDictionary` or other final projection operator.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev  (again), For some reason it seems to require a Key on the view. For this situation that was fine as I had a fake RowNumber that was *mostly* unique on the View. I marked the `.HasKey(x => x.RowNumber)` in the OnModelCreating. Not optimal IMO, but it would work.  It does feel disappointing though, as Framework/EF6 had no issues with this. Seems like a step backwards.

Comment: Hi @Travis (again :-), yes, it is step backwards. But this is not new, it's even considered the normal practice in EF Core (and the whole Net Core line) to have some things new or better, at the same time others worse or totally missing compared to the version they are supposed to replace. It always pissed me off that a "modern" library is lacking "deprecated" library capabilities. But it is what it is, so we have to adjust our code if we want to move forward and be "modern". Debugging/browsing their source code helps only to confirm the bug is there and not in your code.

Comment: But they are constantly changing it, fixing some things, breaking another things, you know. So just adjust your code for the version you are targeting at the moment, and hope they won't break it in the future. With all that said, if you provide the concrete example close to to your real case, I (or someone else) can help finding workaround / solution. As as wrote in the first comment, in general adding some intermediate `Select` after `GroupBy` usually solves such issues. Cheers.